# Как сделать, чтобы onclick срабатывал не один раз

Tags: javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var coin =  document.getElementById('coin');
var degs = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15000 - 2000) + 2000);


function timer(){
    coin.style.transform = "rotateY(" + degs + "deg)";
}

button.addEventListener('click', timer);
```

onclick срабатывает только один раз, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `timer` у вас и так вызывается на каждый клик. А вот в чем действительно проблема, так это в значении переменной `degs`, которое не меняется. Генерируйте его непосредственно при клике:

```
function timer() {
    var degs = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15000 - 2000) + 2000);
    coin.style.transform = "rotateY(" + degs + "deg)";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало)