# Скрипт срабатывает только один раз на событие click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Этот скрипт срабатывает один раз. При клике кнопка блокируется. CSS свойства применяются. Через 5 сек кнопка автоматически разблокируется. Но при последующих нажатиях скрипт не блокирует кнопку и css свойства не применяются

```js
    function timerBlock() {
            $(this).prop('disabled', 'false').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            console.log('Кнопка разблокирована');
        }

    $("#one-form-line").click(function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', 'true').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
        console.log('Кнопка заблокирована');            
        setTimeout(timerBlock, 5000);
    });
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840314/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-onclick-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7

Comment: @ Дмытрык причем тут эта ссылка? Здесь другая проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле в интернете полно уже готовых решений, как на jQuery, так и нa чистом JavaScript:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.attr("disabled","disabled");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $self.removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

То же самое на чистом JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```